# ¿como hacer que python respeto los espacios de linea en whatsapp?

Tags: python, mensajes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from json import load
from turtle import width
import pyautogui as pg

import webbrowser as web
import time
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("contactos.csv",sep= ";", encoding='latin-1')
data_dict = data.to_dict('list')
celulares = data_dict[ 'celular' ]
mensaje = data_dict[ 'mensaje' ]
combo = zip(celulares,mensaje)
first = True
for celulares, mensaje in combo:
    time.sleep(8)
    web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+celulares+"&text="+mensaje)
    if first:
        time.sleep(8)
        firts=False
    width,height = pg.size()
    pg.click(width/2,height/2)
    time.sleep(10)
    pg.press('enter')
    time.sleep(6)
    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
```

quiero que python respete los espacios que le estoy dando desde el archivo .csv, para enviar cadenas de whatsapp pero al momento que se ejecuta el envio no respeta los espacios entre linea y manda como su fuese un solo mensaje. por favor ayuda!!!!

Comment: Sería interesante ver el contenido de `mensaje`, para comprobar si tiene saltos de línea insertos o no.

Comment: @CandidMoe, el mensaje está construido previamente en un archivo Excel que luego se convirtió a .csv y tenía la siguiente estructura en Excel =concatenar("Hola" "*nombre*", carácter(10)*Space sobre la Reforma Tributaria*  Esta noche a las 7:30pmLa semana pasada no pudimos realizarlo, les vuelvo a extender una cordial invitación  Les esperamos  carácter(10) ;"*TWITTER:*" "https://" carácter(10)"*despedida*") utilizando el carácter(10) para los saltos de línea

Comment: Te sugiero analizar un mensaje escrito con la app WS y que contenga dichos saltos de líneas. Algunos sistemas requieren \r\n, etc. Nunca se sabe.

Comment: No funcionó, puesto que WhatsApp web no los reconoce como espacio si no tal cual se escriben \r,\n